# Is it possible to authenticate snowflake users via AD groups?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to authenticate snowflake AD SSO users via an AD group? I've already got SSO set up & working, but I dont want to have to create a separate snowflake user for every person. There will be 100s.

I want it to work like SQL Server authentication where I can add 100s of users to the same group and create a *single login* on SQL Server for the group. To revoke login permissions I just remove the user from the group. To give a new person access I just add them to it.

This is about authentication not authorization (mapping a group to a role), though I may want to do that later.

Comment: A simple google search lands me on this page. https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Use-Active-Directory-Users-and-Groups-for-Snowflake-User-and-Role-Management

Comment: [Azure SCIM Integration with Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-azure.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure automatic user provisioning in Snowflake with AD.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/snowflake-provisioning-tutorial

Capabilities supported:

- Create users in Snowflake
- Remove users in Snowflake when they don't require access anymore
- Keep user attributes synchronized between Azure AD and Snowflake
- Provision groups and group memberships in Snowflake
- Allow single sign-on to Snowflake (recommended)

Comment: Does that work with Snowflake on AWS? Something I read in the tutorial led me to think it only works if you're running Snowflake in Azure.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work, but I haven't tried it. Check also Lukasz link https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-azure.html